# How many ways can a length 100 binary string be written if it starts with 111?

Tags: math, combinations, permutation

I'm currently learning combinatorics and permutations in my discrete math class and had difficulty on my quiz. I got sick earlier this week and missed out on lecture, and thus it's difficult to grasp ahold of this. I understand the basics behind permutations and combinations, but still have difficulty in knowing when to apply them.

As for the question in the title, is this a case of combinations or permutations? I answered with ...

3 * 2^97

I'm unsure if that's correct, though.

Comment: Why multiply by 3?  What if you had a 5 digit binary string that had to start with 111?  What would that look like?

Comment: So what should I do? Remove the 3, I believe then?

Comment: How many length-3 binary strings are there that start with 111? Only 1.  Length-4? 2. Length-5? 4. Length-6? 8. . .

Comment: A length 100 binary string only has four digits . . .

Comment: This question belongs on math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the first three digits do not change (they must be 111), then this would be the same as calculating the the number of ways you can write a binary string with 97 digits.

The first three digits don't change so they do not affect the result.

2^97 is correct.

---

This question is a type of permutation, specifically a [Permutation with repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_with_repetition). Also know as [n-tuples of m-sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple#n-tuples_of_m-sets). The number of n-tuples of an m-set is [image]. In this case the m-set is {0,1} (length 2) and you need all tuples of length 97, so 2^97.

This is not a [combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) because order does not matter in combinations and combinations are generally a subset of the elements of the original set. In our case order does matter and we reuse elements of the original set {0,1} multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Since the order of the digits matters, this is a case of permutations, not combinations.  There are 97 digits of the 100 that can each change to one of 2 states, so there are 2^97 permutations.

This link explains a simple way to remember whether it's a case of permutations or combinations: http://betterexplained.com/articles/easy-permutations-and-combinations/